# After migrating to api 21 toolbar my full screen activity status bar is halfway covering my toolbar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

In my app I use these flags for full screen video. On user interaction I show the nav/status/tool bars. I am using the new api 21 AppCompat with toolbars.

These are the flags I am using when showing the bars:

```
int newVis = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
```

Then calling:

```
mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility( newVis );
```

It worked before migrating to the L toolbars. Presumably now the toolbar is partly covered by the status bar because it is part of the activities layout. I guess I could move the toolbar down by a static amount equal to the height of the status bar but that feels hack-ish. Is there a correct way to accomplish this?

My app supports android 4.1+. Like I said this did not happen before I started using toolbars but it does happen on android 4.1 - 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the fix involved doing some measurements to figure out the size of the action bar and the navigation bar. Because on phone sized devices  in landscape the soft navigation bar ends up on the right side of the display and was also covering up the toolbar. The fix below should work at least on android api-16 to api-21. The latter part of the code is just there to reset an attire for the toolbar that for some reason without that code icons in the action bar end up not being aligned correctly (they were closer to the top). Hope this helps other people.

```
// Get the root activity layout id
            RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.container );
            root.post( new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Point size = new Point();
                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    if ( Integer.valueOf( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK ) >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 )
                    {
                        // This is only available on api 17 and higher
                        display.getRealSize( size );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // On api 16 and less this should work
                        display.getSize( size );
                    }

                    int screenWidth = size.x;

                    Rect rect = new Rect();
                    Window win = getWindow();  // Get the Window
                    win.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame( rect );
                    // Get the height of Status Bar 
                    int statusBarHeight = rect.top;
                    int navBarWidth = screenWidth - rect.width();

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mToolbar.getLayoutParams();

                    android.util.TypedValue value = new android.util.TypedValue();
                    getTheme().resolveAttribute( android.R.attr.actionBarSize, value, true );
                    TypedValue.coerceToString( value.type, value.data );
                    android.util.DisplayMetrics metrics = new android.util.DisplayMetrics();
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( metrics );
                    params.height = (int) value.getDimension( metrics );

                    params.setMargins( 0, statusBarHeight, navBarWidth, 0 );
                    mToolbar.setLayoutParams( params );
                }
            } );
```

Also the root.post(Runnable ...) part is because we cannot measure the window until oncreate has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding a framelayout (height @dimen/statusbarheight). Then you can set the height for each version and mode.

Some examples: attrs.xml:

```
<dimen name="statusbarheight">0dp</dimen>
```

attrs.xml v21:

```
<dimen name="statusbarheight">25dp</dimen>
```

attrs.xml v21 land:

```
<dimen name="statusbarheight">0dp</dimen>
```

When I set translucent navigation bar inside style I got the same problem.

Comment: This does not work. 25dp is not enough height. Also I am not sure the height is the same on all devices. Or is it?

Comment: Standard height is 24dp but I'd be worried this could be changed via some themeing apps.

Comment: I tried the app in nexus 5 and nexus one and 25 dp fix my problem. 24 dp like the google metrics say is wrong for me.

Comment: This is a video testing my app in jb, kk and lollipop in portrait mode and landscape mode with translucent navigation drawer over status bar: http://youtu.be/gHPoCAHfQtg

Comment: Remember set disable the translucent navigation bar in landscape mode too (adding additional boolean to your attrs files)

Comment: I am not sure the status bar is always the same height for all resolutions and manufacturers etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have similar problem on KITKAT. See the [`DrawInsetsFrameLayout` gist by Roman Nurik](https://gist.github.com/romannurik/8919163). The layout should take care of any extra padding and color it.